# Date format in dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to convert datetime from `2012-07-29 10:53:33.010` to
`29/07/2012 10:53:33`.

I tried using

```
select CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 131)
```

but its showing date according to Hijri calendar

```
11/09/1433 10:53:33:
```

Please help?

Comment: CONVERT and GETDATE come from sql server so I guess it SQL Server

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This can be done as follows :

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) + ' '  + convert(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 14)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Just adding that the last code should be 8 if you want to convert to hh:mm:ss, because 14 will convert to hh:mm:ss.fff. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 42):

```
SELECT FORMAT(your_column_name,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss') FROM your_table_name
```

Example-

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss')
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It returns the desired result using one function and one localised style, instead of calling `CONVERT` twice with two generic styles and concatenating strings together, separated by a space.

Answer (score 3):

You could combine 2 formats:

```
3   dd/mm/yy   (British/French)
8   hh:mm:ss
```

according to [`CONVERT()` function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp), and using `+` operator:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),3) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),8)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. My mistake. I thought `CONCAT()` is an old function available from SQL Server 2000. I've replaced it by `+` operator. Thanks for remark.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),GETDATE(),103) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(26),GETDATE(),109),14)
```

Comment: A good answer should include an explanation of the solution, instead of just posting code.

Answer (score 0):

The chapter on [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) on MSDN Books Online, you've missed the right answer by one line.... you can use style no. 121 (*ODBC canonical (with milliseconds)*) to get the result you're looking for:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 121)
```

This gives me the output of:

```
2012-04-14 21:44:03.793
```

**Update:** based on your updated question - of course this won't work - you're converting a string (this: `'4/14/2012 2:44:01 PM'` is **just a string** - it's **NOT** a datetime!) to a string......

You need to **first** convert the string you have to a `DATETIME` and **THEN** convert it back to a string!

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST('4/14/2012 2:44:01 PM' AS DATETIME), 121)
```

Now you should get:

```
2012-04-14 14:44:01.000
```

All zeroes for the milliseconds, obviously, since your original values didn't include any ....

Comment: The output the OP is requesting is `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, not `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION DBO.ConvertDateToVarchar
(
@DATE DATETIME
)

RETURNS VARCHAR(24) 
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),@DATE, 121))
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s') 
  from dual
```

Try this wherever required, I have used this in JpaRepository in SpringBoot Project.

Answer (score -1):

This will be `varchar` but should format as you need.

```
RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(DAY(d)), 2) + '/'
+ RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(MONTH(d)), 2) + '/'
+ LTRIM(YEAR(d)) + ' '
+ RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(DATEPART(HOUR, d)), 2) + ':'
+ RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(DATEPART(MINUTE, d)), 2) + ':'
+ RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(DATEPART(SECOND, d)), 2)
```

Where `d` is your `datetime` field or variable.