# Change date format in SQL server using Java code

Tags: java, sql-server, datetime

I have a column "created_date" in my table in SQL server. It is currently in format "dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss" and I want to change it to "yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss" using Java code.

Simple date format is throwing error. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Date, and time, values in SQL Server don't have a format; they are stored as a binary value with no formatting information. If your value(s) truly have a "format" then they are by definition *not* a date and time value, but a string (`varchar`) value.

Comment: Yes it is varchar. So how can I update it now in Java code?

Comment: I would suggest you fix your design; storing date and time values as something other than a date and time data type is a design flaw.

Comment: The best thing you can do is fix that column so that it's an actual date column, not a varchar.  But if you don't want to do that, you can write an SQL statement to modify the values in it.  It's nothing to do with Java though - there's no point in writing a Java program to do it.

Comment: your created_date is varchar change it to datetime by using following query update yourtable set created_date= CONVERT(DATETIME,created_date,103);

Comment: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707665/date-format-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss)

Comment: "using Java code" -> use the classes of `java.time` package and its sub-packages (`java.time.format`), like [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)  || converting formats of dates is a common question on StackOverflow

Comment: `yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss` is a funny format. What makes you think that someone will be happy about it? If formatting for human users, use their locale. See for example [Guide to DateTimeFormatter, section *3. DateTimeFormatter With FormatStyle*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-datetimeformatter#formatStyle).